# YII2 Проверка есть ли запись в закладках у пользователя List View

Tags: база-данных, yii2, listview

На главной выводится список записей. Нужно как-то сделать чтобы из таблицы **AchieveUser** проверялось добавлена ли эта запись в базу данных к данному пользователю (типа как закладка, что он сохранил эту запись). При этом к добавленным статьям приписывается "Добавлено".

Я не понимаю как в этом коде, в условие WHERE, подставить id модели(achieve) чтобы он проверял каждую статью в ListView. Или это как-то по-другому делается?

**CONTROLLER - AchieveController.php**

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new AchieveSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if (AchieveUser::find()->where([
       'id_user' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id, 
       'id_achieve' => ****ЧТО СЮДА ПИСАТЬ****
       ])->exists()){
        $exist="Добавлено";
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'exist' => $exist,
    ]);
}
```

**VIEW - index.php**

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => '_list_item',
    'viewParams' => [
       'exist' => $exist
    ],
]) ?>
```

**VIEW - _list_item.php**

```
    <?php
        echo $exist;
        echo $model->title;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вытащил сразу из базы id всех статей которые добавлены у пользователя в закладках

**ActiveRecord**

```
$achieve = AchieveUser::find()->where([
           'id_user' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id
           ])->all())
```

**или DAO**

```
$query = new Query();
$achieve = $query->select(['id'])->from('achieve_user')->where('id_user = :user', [':user' = Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->createCommand()->queryAll();
```

Собрал бы массив из айдишников.
А во вью уже проверял бы каждую статью

```
echo (in_array($model->id, $achieveIds)) ? 'Добавлено' : '';
```

Или перенес бы данный код в модель, дабы не засорять вьюху